# Illegal connection string

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to deploy an azure function, precisely a EventHubTrigger, but I am unable to run it, I get the following error message:

> [16-10-2019 11:40:32] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing
>   method 'Functions.Log10EventHubTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs:
>   Illegal connection string parameter name 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol'
>   [16-10-2019 11:40:32] Parameter name: connectionString. [16-10-2019
>   11:40:32] Error indexing method 'Functions.Log10EventHubTrigger'
>   [16-10-2019 11:40:32] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing
>   method 'Functions.Log10EventHubTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs:
>   Illegal connection string parameter name 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol'
>   [16-10-2019 11:40:32] Parameter name: connectionString.

I have used both connections strings available on my storage, and the error is still there!
Any idea what might be causing this issue and how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you set the connecting string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

**Original Answer:**

I can reproduce your problem.

[image]

From your description I guess you used Storage's Connecting String, but you also say you used EventHubTrigger. So that is the problem. I think you need to read the **Offical doc**[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger)[[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/) to learn the EventHubTrigger Clearly.

***Solution is change the path of the Connecting string to EntityPath(your eventhub name).***

Comment: thanks for the reply, indeed I am super new to Azure, I'll read the docs in the links you provided and see if I can solve the issue!

Comment: I have added teh entityPath, when debugging I don't the the error with the connection string anymore, although, when I deploy the function to Azure, I get a new error: "Indexing method x. Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: receiverConnectionString"

Comment: can you elaborate on your last comment? I dont really understand what you mean! I have also notice the following on my debug window, although I have already installed grpcio using pip! "[17-10-2019 09:47:34]   File "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\azure-functions-core-tools\tools\workers\python\deps\grpc\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
[17-10-2019 09:47:34]     from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc"

Comment: From your comment, it seems you deploy from local? So did you set it in the local.setting.json ?

Comment: Yes I did! my local.setting.json looks like:                                                                 
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "EventHubConnectionString":"Endpoint=..",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;..",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}

Comment: @ElviroPereirajunior This seems like a python issue. I am not good at python. This may help you:https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1462

Comment: where to set it in the portal? I did add the same connectionstring to the function.json, parameter name: receiverConnectionString

Comment: @ElviroPereirajunior No, don't do that. If you deploy to azure, you need set app settings on portal. local.setting.json only work for local running. I will update my answer.

Comment: @ElviroPereirajunior I updated the answer and you can have a try. You may not have set it up, but this should not be the cause of this error. You can have a look of the url that I give you just now. I think that is the cause because he faced the same issue with you.

Comment: I managed the issue with grpc, turns out you can only get that library with python64 bit, and I was running 32bit version! the pictures you left above also helped with the issue with 'receiverConnectionString'

Comment: @ Hi, If my solution solve your problems, you can take my solution as the answer of this question. This will help others when they meet the same question. Thank you for your contribution to the community！